# Filtering through CD relationships in swift

Tags: swift

How can an array of person objects be extracted from an array of memberships that have person.personId != self.id?

For an array of memberships, each has a person object. I would like to get all the person objects directly for all other persons.

If getting the first one like this

```
if let memberships = self.memberships.allObjects as? [Membership],
        let person = memberships.filter({$0.person.personId != userId}).first?.person {
```

How can every person be extracted and returned in an array using swifts collection functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
if let memberships = self.memberships.allObjects as? [Membership] {

    // Filter to remove the membership with userID,
    // and then map to an array of people

    let people = memberships.filter({$0.person.personId != userId}).map { $0.person }
}
```

Somewhere it looks like you are going to need to `map` an array of `Membership`s to an array of `person` objects. Hopefully if the above isn't exactly right it will point you in the right direction.